# Add prefix to router while still showing it in API root view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

To simplify my question, I have a Django project with two apps: `devices` and `pins` with the following urls.py:

```
# devices/urls.py

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'relays', api_views.RelayViewSet)
router.register(r'ultrasonic_sensors', api_views.UltrasonicSensorViewSet)
router.register(r'contact_sensors', api_views.ContactSensorViewSet)
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

```
# pins/urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'pins', api_views.PinViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

and the main project's urls.py looks like this:

```
from devices.urls import router as devices_router
from pins.urls import router as pins_router

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(pins_router.urls)),
    path('devices/', include(devices_router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

**Question:** I want to "group" or prefix all `device_router` urls with `/devices/` while still showing it on the root API view.

Currently, I *can* view `/devices/relays/<pk>`, however it is not shown in the root API view of DRF.

Current result when calling the root path:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "pins": "http://pinode:8000/pins/"
}
```

Required result:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "pins": "http://pinode:8000/pins/",
    "devices": "http://pinode:8000/devices/"
}
```

Where `http://pinode:8000/devices/` shows the following:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "relays": "http://pinode:8000/devices/relays/",
    "ultrasonic_sensors": "http://pinode:8000/devices/ultrasonic_sensors/",
    "contact_sensors": "http://pinode:8000/devices/contact_sensors/",
}
```